# How to extract certain lines from text file by REGEX

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have this complicated text file with over 22,000 lines:

```
>Cluster 35
0   2856nt, >tru_clu8_1_inde2_or1... *
>Cluster 36
0   1179nt, >gl_isotig07707... *
1   914nt, >un_isotig04557... at +/94.20%
2   1282nt, >cp_isotig06284... at -/92.43%
3   1137nt, >cp_isotig02981... at -/93.84%
>Cluster 37
0   2835nt, >yl_JTQ_com670_c0_seq1... *
>Cluster 38
0   2275nt, >pb_iso00211... at +/93.93%
1   2647nt, >yl_JTQ_com323_c0_seq1... at +/91.39%
```

I want clusters with only 1 hit:

```
>Cluster 35
0     2856nt, >tru_clu8_1_inde2_or1... *
>Cluster 37
0     2835nt, >yl_JTQ_com670_c0_seq1... *
```

Then if possible output in this format:

```
>Cluster 35   tru_clu8_1_inde2_or1
>Cluster 37   yl_JTQ_com670_c0_seq1
```

Comment: I tried a simple regex to bring first hits (0... ) to Clusters line and then grep with > . But it messed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>2{if(/^>/ && b ~ /^>/) print b"\n"a} {b=a ; a=$0}' infile.txt
>Cluster 35
0   2856nt, >tru_clu8_1_inde2_or1... *
>Cluster 37
0   2835nt, >yl_JTQ_com670_c0_seq1... *
```

**Edit:**

This will however not work if there is a final cluster with one hit. This workaround may work, also includes formatted output:

```
$ echo ">" >> infile.txt
$ awk 'NR>2{if(/^>/ && b ~ /^>/) {a=gensub(/^.*>(\w+).*/,"\\1", "g", a) ; print b,a} } {b=a ; a=$0}' infile.txt
>Cluster 35 tru_clu8_1_inde2_or1
>Cluster 37 yl_JTQ_com670_c0_seq1
```

Comment: Great. This is useful in this step. If I change a=$0 to a=$0 $1, I will get clusters with 2 hits?

Comment: not sure, am still learning awk.. and my solution won't work if there is a final cluster with one entry

Comment: Right. It excluded the last entry which is with 1 hit.

Comment: for two hit cluster, `awk 'NR>3{if(/^>/ && c ~ /^>/) {print c"\n"b"\n"a} } {c=b; b=a; a=$0}'` and use gensub accordingly..

Answer (score 1):

Following regex works for me:

```
^>.*\d\R.*$\R(\D)
```

You can check it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/uN8jF8/1)